Cannot use other string indexes when using a generic type inside of a type
Here is my code:
export type CommandOptionType = string | number | boolean;
export type CommandOption = Record<string, CommandOptionType>;

export type LeafCommand<T extends CommandOption> = {
    name: string;
    handle: (
        interactionOptionValues: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] },
    ) => Promise<void>;
};

export type LeafCommandGroup = {
    name: string;
    commands: Record<string, LeafCommand<CommandOption>>;
};

export type RootCommand = {
    name: string;
    commands: Record<string, LeafCommandGroup | LeafCommand<CommandOption>>;
};

Usage of these types:
type OPTIONS = {
    option1: "type1" | "type2" | "type3" | "type4";
    option2: string;
    option3: boolean;
};

const Type = {
    name: "type",
    handle: async (interactionOptionValues) => {
        // business logic here
    },
} satisfies LeafCommand<OPTIONS>;

The error occurs below code snippet:
const Root = {
    name: "root",
    commands: { // error occurs here
        [Type.name]: Type,
    },
} satisfies RootCommand;

Here, I'm getting the error which says Type { [x: string]: CommandOptionType } is missing the following properties from type. option1, option2, option3. I don't know why Typescript complains about other index keys which are strings as well. I couldn't find a work around.
Desired result is that I should be able to add commands which has type of LeafCommand without a hustle.
If you have any other design patterns that is cleverer, I'm down for it.
Thanks for your time.

If the question is "why is this happening" based on your title and "I'm getting the error/I don't know why", it's because what you're doing is unsafe, see this demonstration. Functions are contravariant in their parameter types. You can't assign a (a: X)=>void to a (a: Y)=>void if X is assignable to Y. It's the other way around, Y has to be assignable to X. So if you're looking for a supertype of LeafCommand<T> you want LeafCommand<never> and not LeafCommand<CommandOption>. Does this fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

Thanks for your valuable comment @jcalz. I also assumed the same reasoning for the error. However, I wondered why other "string" indexes make Typescript complain. As you can see in this demo, when you are using Record with "string" key indexes, you can access undefined properties and Typescript does not complain. I assumed the same thing would happen in my situation. It seems this super-safe check occurs for functions, as you mentioned.
You can create your answer, and I'll mark it as a solution. Also, if you have better design ideas, let me know!

Now you're talking about --noUncheckedIndexedAccess and it's really not directly related to the question as asked other than them both appearing in your code; TS being strict/sound in one feature but lax/unsound in another is just how it is. I won't worry about undefined on index signatures when answering this question, if you don't mind.

Your LeafCommand<T> type is contravariant in T (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript) because T appears as the parameter type of a function.  That means LeafCommand<T> extends LeafCommand<U> if U extends T, and not vice versa.  So since OPTIONS extends CommandOption, you can only conclude that LeafCommand<CommandOption> extends LeafCommand<OPTIONS>. The opposite, which is what you're doing, is not true... because it's not safe.  For example:
let lcO: LeafCommand<OPTIONS> =
  { name: "", handle(o) { o.option2.toUpperCase(); return Promise.resolve() } };
let lcCO: LeafCommand<CommandOption> = lcO; // error, for good reason!
lcCO.handle({}); // error at runtime, o.option2 is undefined

If you assign a LeafCommand<OPTIONS> to a LeafCommand<CommandOption>, then when you call the handle() method and give it a CommandOption, the implementation will assume that it got an OPTIONS, and if this assumption is wrong you can easily get runtime errors.

If you're looking for a type to which all LeafCommand<T>s are assignable no matter what T is, then you need a type which is assignable to all Ts. The only way that will work is to use the never type:
type RootCommand = {
  name: string;
  commands: Record<string, LeafCommandGroup | LeafCommand<never>>;
};

const Root = {
  name: "root",
  commands: { // okay now
    [Type.name]: Type,
  },
} satisfies RootCommand;

This might or might not end up satisfying your underlying use case (you'll find yourself unhappy if you try to call a handle() on LeafCommand<never>, but that's just a consequence of contravariance), but it's at least type safe.
Playground link to code
